# SQL Job Fails - Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql-server, jobs, sqlcmd, sp-send-dbmail

In a Query Window, it completes as expected and sends the dbmail, but when I put the same syntax in a Job it fails. All other jobs on the server are working and sending mail as expected. I also have a second job that is almost identical, selecting * from a view in the same DB and that is working. This job just started failing yesterday in the middle of the day.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='Admin',
@recipients='email@company.com; email2@company.com',
@query='SELECT * FROM sql1.database.intake.vwSelectMissing1',
@subject='Matters Missing in Database',
@query_result_header = 1
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was need for one job but not for another, but I added one line to this job.  EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'sa'

Comment: maybe the step "Run as" is not set to sa in this one , check it out